# dendextend get_subdendrograms in R: changing label names causes subdendrograms to be NULL

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram, dendextend

I am trying to create subdendrograms using dendextend, this works until I change the names of the labels of the leaves in the dendrogram. I want the labels to be 'Y' or 'B' based on a column in my dataframe. If I do this it causes several of the subdendrograms to be NULL.

Here is some reproducible code

```
library(dplyr)
library(dendextend)

new_labels <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")

new_colors <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1)

# define dendrogram object to play with:
dend <- iris[, -5] %>%
  dist() %>%
  hclust() %>%
  as.dendrogram() %>%
  # change the color of the labels
  set('labels_colors', new_colors[order.dendrogram(.)]) %>% 
  # change the labels to 'Y' or 'B'
  set('labels', new_labels[order.dendrogram(.)]) %>% 
  color_branches(k = 5)

dend_list <- get_subdendrograms(dend, 5)

# Plotting the result
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
plot(dend, main = "Original dendrogram")
sapply(dend_list, plot)
```

If I run this without the line

`set('labels', new_labels[order.dendrogram(.)]) %>%`

then it works fine, in that I get a plot with the main dendrogram and 5 subdendrograms, and the labels are colored (black or grey).

However, if I run with this line

`set('labels', new_labels[order.dendrogram(.)]) %>%`

then I get NULL types in the dend_list, and only 1 of 5 subdendrograms is added to the plot. The one that is in the plot is formatted correctly with 'Y' and 'B' labels.

I have tried lots of things but I'm not sure how to fix this. Does anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have the answer (with some help from Bing Chat)

The solution was to change the labels of the main dendrogram, and of the sub dendrograms *after* the sub dendrograms were extracted. Updated code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dendextend)

new_labels <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "B", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
                "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")

new_colors <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                1, 1, 1, 1)

# define dendrogram object to play with:
dend <- iris[, -5] %>%
  dist() %>%
  hclust() %>%
  as.dendrogram() %>%
  # color the labels according to their values
  set('labels_colors', new_colors[order.dendrogram(.)]) %>% 
  color_branches(k = 5)

dend_list <- get_subdendrograms(dend, 5)
# after extracting the sub dendrograms: add labels to the original dend
labels(dend) <- paste(new_labels[order.dendrogram(dend)])
# and add labels to the sub dendrograms
dend_list <- lapply(dend_list, function(x) set(x, 'labels', new_labels[order.dendrogram(x)]))

# Plotting the result
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
plot(dend, main = "Original dendrogram")
sapply(dend_list, plot)
```